# powerpoint: set default paste

Tags: windows, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

Is there any way to set the default paste (crtl+V) to paste enhanced bitmap in the latest Microsoft Powerpoint? Maybe using a regedit value?

The best I can come up with is crtl+alt+v, but it's a bit annoying and Windows Word has the option to change default pasting.

[related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476119/how-can-i-make-windows-metafile-my-default-paste-special-option-in-word-2007)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, of the Microsoft Office products, only Word supports defaults, and these defaults are only set for pasting Text.

Theoretically you could write a macro (VBA) for Powerpoint that sets an effective default for you, and the post you've already linked has information on that.

This is the current documentation for pasting in Office, and it confirms that only Word supports setting defaults: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/control-the-formatting-when-you-paste-text-20156a41-520e-48a6-8680-fb9ce15bf3d6